# Can't connect remotely to WAS 8.5 full profile installed on Ubuntu 14.04 from RAD 9.5 installed on OSX

Tags: macos, ubuntu, websphere, websphere-8, sshd

**WAS 8.5 full profile** [isn't officially supported on OSX by **IBM**](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/6124/remote-deploy-from-eclipse-juno-sr2-to-was-8-5-5.html) so the only option to perform development from **OSX** is to install stub runtime and connect to **WAS** installed remotely. I'm trying to install such scenario but something done wrong and can't connect to my **WAS**.

There's my installation:

On **OSX El Capitan** Installed:

- **RAD 9.5** with **WAS 8.5** stub runtime (`WebSphere Application Server traditional V8.5 stub`)
- Installed **Virtual Box** with **Ubuntu** Desktop edition **14.04**
- Ubuntu's hostname: `anatoly-ubuntu-vm` and it's accessible from host, i.e. `ping anatoly-ubuntu-vm` works fine
- On Ubuntu installed:

  - WAS 8.5 full profile at `/opt/IBM/WebSphere`
  - Created `AppSrv01` profile at `/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles`
  - WAS installed with root user, **IBM Installation Manager** required root permission when was started

My connection settings in RAD:

- server name: `WebSphere Application Server traditional V8.5 stub at anatoly-ubuntu-vm`
- hostname: `anatoly-ubuntu-vm`
- Runtime environment: `WebSphere Application Server traditional V8.5 stub`
- Connection type:

  - I've tried `RMI 2809` and `SOAP 8880` both options didn't work
  - `Enable the server to start remotely` is checked and `Select the operating system running the remote server:` checked `Linux` option with my username and password. I've tried my regular Ubuntu account and root, both option didn't work.
  - `Server profile path` defined as `/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01`

When I try to start server I get the following exception:

> The following problems has occurred when starting the server.
>   CTGRI0001E The application could not establish a connection to
>   anatoly-ubuntu-vm .

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1:**

After I've written this post I've figured out that SSH server isn't installed and configured at all as described here: [Requirements for using Remote Execution and Access (RXA)](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.installation.nd.doc/ae/cins_cim_rxa_requirements.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5&view=embed) Now, I've installed and it seems like connecting but stuck at 23% at stage `Preparing launch delegate`, after a while it throw the following error:

> The following problems has occurred when starting the server. The
>   server may not be started in the correct mode.  You can restart the
>   server to desired mode if it is started. CTGRI0075E A file transfer to
>   or from the system named [anatoly-ubuntu-vm]  timed out before the
>   transfer could complete. The current timeout interval is set to 240000
>   milliseconds, and might need to be increased.

**UPDATE 2:**
As I can see despite error message server is started and I even can connect to web console `anatoly-ubuntu-vm:9060/console/ibm` but it looks that not SOAP connection, neither RMI connection don't work. When I run **Test Connection** from Settings overview page in RAD, I get the following error:

> The connection failed after trying to use all the available connection
>   types.
>
> Verify the port values are correct and the server has been started. If
>   the security of the server is enabled, verify the "Security is enabled
>   on this server" check box is selected, and the user ID and password
>   are provided. You can specify this in the server editor or when
>   creating a new server.
>
> For a Technote with details on the most common server connection
>   problem, see http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21266028.
>
> The last connection attempt failed with the following exception:
>   ADMC0016E: The system cannot create a SOAP connector to connect to
>   host anatoly-ubuntu-vm at port 8880.

**UPDATE 3**
As @DanielBarbarian guessed I tried to run `./wsadmin.sh -port 8880` and it worked and returned

> Connected to process "server1" on node anatoly-ubuntu-vmNode01 using SOAP connector;  The type of process is: UnManagedProcess`

This is settings of my ports:

[image]

**UPDATE 4**
When I trying to run `telnet anatoly-ubuntu-vm 8880` from OSX host I get the following response (ip address changed to non real due to privacy issue):

```
anatoly-mac:~ anatoly$ telnet anatoly-ubuntu-vm 8880 
Trying 192.168.10.10... 
Connected to anatoly-ubuntu-vm 
Escape character is '^]'. 
HTTP/1.1 408 Request Timeout

Content-Type: text/html 
Content-Length: 117 
Connection: close

<HTML><TITLE>408 - Request Timeout</TITLE><BODY>
<h1>408 Connection timed out while reading request</h1></BODY>
</HTML>Connection closed by foreign host
```

Comment: And I assume you have double checked that ports 2809 and 8880 are in fact the ports that are configured for `RMI` and `SOAP` respectively for your server?
Have you tried connecting via `RMI` or `SOAP` in another way, such as a wsAdmin client?

Comment: @DanielBarbarian, `SOAP` yes, `RMI` I not sure, you can see screenshot of my settings, I've updated my question (**UPDATE 3**). `wsAdmin` can successfully connect to `SOAP` port. Thank you.

Comment: Ok (and yes it seems like RMI port is correct as well), do you run wsAdmin locally on the server or on your RAD machine? Have you tried to connect to your server just by accessing the port? Something like `telnet anatoly-ubuntu-vm 8880`.

Comment: Ok, so it seems like you actually can connect. Then it could be an authentication failure. Have you entered the username and password in the configuration for the WAS server in RAD?

Comment: @Anatoly have you discovered the issue? I'm having it as well but strange thing is that it worked when I first set it up

Comment: @bluefoot, sorry, it was a long time ago. I remember that it was an issue with network settings, but don't remember how exactly out IT team has solved it if at all :(

Comment: Oddly enough, creating a fresh workspace from scratch did it for me. The workspace I was using came from an old windows installation and had lots of broken references in it.